# Unable to determine spaces to align the columns of a Gradebook program

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am making a Gradebook program for a school project. The goal is to make a program that when given the names of students, max scores for assignments, assignment names, and the scores received on them, will print out the data stored in arrays in a cube-like shape. These columns must be aligned and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do that.
This is the code that I am trying to use to space it properly.

```
for(int j = 0; j < hwScores[row].length; j++)
{
    int k; //i do this because the variable needs to be stored after the first for loop to print the variable
    int pos = hwNames[j].length()/2; //this is to find out where the actual score should be placed
    for(k = 0; k <= pos - new Double(hwScores[row][j]).toString().length(); k++)//this gets me the length of the double so that i can determine where to put it in the box. I use it only to tell the program how many spaces should come before the number and how many after, which is the next for loop.
        System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print(hwScores[row][j]);//this prints the actual value of the score
    for(k = 0; k <= pos - new Double(hwScores[row][j]).toString().length() + 1; k++)
        System.out.print(" ");
    System.out.print('|');
}
```

The following is the code that handles the names and values of the assignments

```
public void drawHWNames(String[] x, String[] names)
{
    corner = getLongestString(names);
    for(int i = 0; i < corner; i++)
        System.out.format(" ");
    System.out.print("| ");
    for(String s: x)
    {
        System.out.printf("%3s", s + " | ");
    }
}
/*
 * takes the names of the tests and prints them after the homework names are printed
 */
public void drawTestNames(String[] x)
{
    for(String s: x)
    {
        System.out.printf("%3s", s + " | ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
/*
 * this takes the array holding the values of the homwork assignments and prints them to the screen
 */
public void drawHWValues(int[] x, String[] hwnames)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < corner; i++)
        System.out.format(" ");
    System.out.print("|");
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        int pos = hwnames[i].length();
        for(int j = 0; j <= (pos - new Integer(x[i]).toString().length() + 1)/2; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(x[i]);
        for(int j = 0; j <= (pos - new Integer(x[i]).toString().length() + 1)/2; j++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print('|');
    }
}
/*
 * this takes the array containing the values of the tests and the names of the tests and draws them onto the screen
 */
public void drawTestValues(int[] x, String[] testnames)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        int pos = testnames[i].length()/2;
        for(int j = 0; j <= pos - new Integer(x[i]).toString().length(); j++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(x[i]);
        for(int j = 0; j <= pos - new Integer(x[i]).toString().length(); j++)
            System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print('|');
    }
}
```

This gave the following output

[image]

I am unable to post images at this time so sorry for that.

The rest of the calculator is working as intended but the alignment has been the one thing that has been tripping me up. If there is something that you need cleared up make sure to tell me and I will do my best to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help if you use a formatted print option (printf, or format)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

EDIT2:  Here is new code, modeled somewhat after your code, however simplified based on the use of System.out.format.  The output is nicely formatted.  I suggest you try this new code, and then substitute your variables, etc.  But in principal is solves your alignment issues.

public class TestPrintf {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String hwnames[] = {"hw 1", "hw 2", "hw 3", "hw 4", "hw 5", "test 1", "test 2", "test 3"};
    int hwnvalues[] = {20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30};

    int[][] x = {{20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30},
            {20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30},
            {20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30},
            {20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30},
            {20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30}};
    String testNames[] = {"really", "am", "sick", "of", "this"};
    String percentages[] = {"82.5", "90", "92", "88", "95"};

    drawHeader(hwnames);
    System.out.println();
    drawHeaderValue(hwnvalues);
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i<testNames.length; i++)
        drawValues(testNames[i], x[i], percentages[i]);
}

public static void drawValues(String header, int[] values, String percentage) {
    System.out.format("%6s |", header);
    for (int i = 0; i<values.length; i++) {
        System.out.format("%7.1f |", (double)values[i]);
    }
    System.out.format("%7.2f", Double.valueOf(percentage));
    System.out.println("%");
}

public static void drawHeader(String[] hwnames) {
    System.out.format("%6s |", " ");
    for(int i = 0; i < hwnames.length; i++)
        System.out.format("%7s |", hwnames[i]);
}
public static void drawHeaderValue(int[] hwvalues) {
    System.out.format("%6s |", " ");
    for(int i = 0; i < hwvalues.length; i++)
        System.out.format("%7d |", hwvalues[i]);
}
```

}

Output:

```
       |   hw 1 |   hw 2 |   hw 3 |   hw 4 |   hw 5 | test 1 | test 2 | test 3 |
       |     20 |     20 |     20 |     20 |     20 |     30 |     30 |     30 |
really |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   30.0 |   30.0 |   30.0 |  82.50%
    am |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   30.0 |   30.0 |   30.0 |  90.00%
  sick |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   30.0 |   30.0 |   30.0 |  92.00%
    of |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   30.0 |   30.0 |   30.0 |  88.00%
  this |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   20.0 |   30.0 |   30.0 |   30.0 |  95.00%
```

Comment: I am fairly confused about how I would integrate this into my code as I do not fully understand what that would do. The main issue is that the data changes, so they have to match the upper columns. I can edit my code to give you the entire method if that would help in any way. Sorry for being such an idiot...

Comment: No need to apologize - this is the first time you have seen formatted printing.  It can apply to the headers, as well as the body.  The key is the match them up.  It would help if you posted the code for your headers.  There will be a System.out.format("%Xs" as well, where the 'X' makes it line up.  Unfortunately I am done for the day.  Either someone will have to take over, or if you wait until morning I will correct all your code to work (if you post the entire thing).  Cheers.

Comment: I have added the methods that are used to print the assignment names and values. thanks for your help on this it really is appreciated.

Comment: Here is some new code, which you can study in the meantime, and let me know if you have any questions.  It was hard for me to change your code in a short time, but I hope this helps.

Comment: I entered the code but your draw header method doesn't accept the hw values integer array you gave it.  Is there any code missing from that? Also the scores are stored in 2separate 2d arrays, where you made one

Comment: The new code now supports hw values as an int array (see drawHeaderValue(int [])).  Please explain further what you mean with the 2 separate 2d arrays.  Thanks.

Comment: I have managed to get the code fully functional. Thank you so much for your help in showing me how to use the formatting options. I implemented those and it worked flawlessly. As for the 2 2d arrays. Our teacher said to have one 2d array for the homework scores and one 2d array for the test scores. Which made it more difficult to implement your code. I marked your answer as the solution, and really thank you so much for helping me out with this.

Comment: Your welcome.  Well done getting your assignment working!